# Cisco機器のSNMP設定のバージョンを v2c に下げる事にリスクはありますか？

Tags: snmp

SNMPの設定をしているのですが、トラップ取得を行ってくれない為、バージョンを1個下げようと思っています。その際に発生しそうなリスクはありますか？

現状の設定はv3で、v2cにしようとしています。
v2cではトラップ取得は出来ているので、バージョン自体は問題ないはずです。